# What do ジャンルくじイラスト and デリケートなジャンル mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, katakana, na-adjectives, wasei-eigo

My circle (student club) at a Japanese university is preparing for the school festival. One option for participating is to draw and submit a 「ジャンルくじイラスト」. Does this translate to "genre lottery illustration"?
What does that mean?  Does it mean that each submitted illustration is not guaranteed to be featured in the festival booth, but that the illustrations used in the festival will be selected out of all of the submitted illustrations by random?  Or does it mean that the genres to choose from for drawing the illustration were determined by lottery?  Or...?

Here is the full paragraph:
「ジャンルくじイラスト募集要項
　　ジャンルが書かれたくじを引いてそれに書かれたジャンルのイラストを書く、ジャンルくじイラスト企画を今年も行います。くじを引く人は例会、その他の場所で学祭担当が対応します。参加は各自の自由。」

The rules also state,「デリケートなジャンルに関しては各自自重する（ディズニーとか）」. 
What is デリケートなジャンル, and what is 各自自重する?
I Googled デリケートなジャンル but could not determine a basic definition that seemed to apply to the various webpages that came up.  What constitutes a genre as "delicate"?  I tried looking up 各自自重する in online dictionaries but I could not find an English translation.  Is this saying that if you want to draw Disney characters you need to make them original in some way?  Is it possibly saying that fanart is not allowed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: イラストを書く>> It's a typo for イラストを描く, no?

Comment: I think so; usually the club members use 「描く」.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ジャンルくじイラスト募集要項 states that they are going to hold a ジャンルくじイラスト企画 again this year. Participants will be requested to draw a lottery with a topic written on it (=ジャンルが書かれたくじを引いて) at 例会 or その他の場所 and draw an illustration that's related to the topic written on the lottery (=それに書かれたジャンルのイラストを描く). If you want to draw a lottery (=くじを引く人は、), their staff members (=学祭担当) will let you do so (=対応します) at 例会 or その他の場所. Participation is not obligatory (=参加は各自の自由). So I think it means that the topic for your illustration will be determined by lottery.

> デリケートなジャンルに関しては各自自重する（ディズニーとか）

各自自重する means 各自で自重してください, 各自で自粛してください or 自分たちで判断して自粛してください.  I think they're saying that you should refrain from drawing copyrighted characters such as Disney characters, so yes, I think they're saying "fanart is not allowed". As for the デリケートな, I'm not sure but probably they meant to say 微妙な, "sensitive", "iffy" or "something that requires (special) care/attention"?

Comment: 「ジャンル」 does not mean "genre" here; It means more like "topic" or "theme" in present-day informal Japanese.　"Disney" is not a genre for drawing.　This is like how 「プリン」 does not mean "pudding" but it means "flan" nearly 100% of the time.  Examples of katakana words that bilingual dictionaries usually do not give accurate counterparts for.

Comment: ありがとうございます。editさせて頂きました。おこりんぼ！